# How to get the all the combination using permutation with condition

Tags: python, python-itertools

```
from itertools import permutations 
permList = permutations('ABC')
for perm in list(permList): 
       print (''.join(perm))
```

Output

```
ABC
ACB
BAC
BCA
CAB
CBA
```

How to include get the combination of the 2 letters also along with above output, basically i need to define minimum length has to start is `2`

Another example a string `ABCDE` here i need to start the minum permutation from 3
`(len(list)) < 3 has to avoided`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious way is to have a `for` loop to iterate through different values of the `r` parameter for the `permutations`:

```py
from itertools import permutations 

for x in range(2,4):
    for perm in permutations('ABC', r=x): 
           print (''.join(perm))
```

Note that you can iterate directly from the object returned from the `permutations` (as it is an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable)).

---

Analogously to get all the permutations with more than three elements, you could use:

```py
from itertools import permutations 

for x in range(3, len("ABCDE") + 1):
    for perm in permutations('ABCDE', r=x): 
           print (''.join(perm))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
given_list = [1,2,3,4,5]

min_num = 2

for x in range(min_num, len(given_list)):
    perm = permutations(given_list, x)
    all_perms.extend(perm)
```

You'll get all permutations with atleast `min_num` values.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like permutations can take a second argument that dictates the length. https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

```
from itertools import permutations 
input_str = 'ABC'
min_len = 2
max_len = len(input_str)

perm_list = []

for l in range(2, max_len + 1):
    l_permList = list(permutations(input_str, l))
    perm_list += l_permList

print (perm_list)
```